# How secure is Django

Tags: django, security

A client of mine asked me this question. I am not even sure what to reply ? I am no security expert, just a web dev. What can must I say ?

Comment: You mighy want to read [Django book chapter on security](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter20/) .

Comment: Django provides the fire extinguisher, but it's up to you to put out the fire.

Comment: @rebus: I think you just about summed up all of the answers in this thread.

Answer (score 32):

By default, Django prevents most common security mistakes:

- **XSS (cross-site scripting) protection** — Django template system by default escapes variables, unless they are explicitly marked as safe.
- **CSRF (cross site request forgery) protection** — easy to turn on globally, guarantees that forms (POST requests) are sent from your own site.
- **SQL injection protection** — Django uses built-in ORM, thus there is no risk of SQL injection (raw queries are possible, but by no means something that a beginner would need to use).

Additional security features:

- [**Clickjacking protection**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/clickjacking/) — Django can detect when the content is requested from unauthorized `iframe`
- **Safe password hash** — Django by default uses [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), another option is [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Both are resilient to usage of rainbow tables (thanks to salt), both have significant compute time to prevent easy bruteforce.

It's also important to note, that Django is implemented in Python, which has excellent security track record. Thus the underlying language is not a security risk.

More on Django security: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/security/

Comment: Historically, no, it is a cluster-crap of exploits, both in Django and Python it runs on. You will not find your bank running their banking site on Django. Ever.
https://snyk.io/vuln/pip:django

Comment: @TonyB yeah, right... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEo7I8N8zlU

Comment: Good find!  ... one bank (sort of) in the world using Django. Not sure that is best role model example, but points for finding it.

https://fintech.global/2020/07/01/holvi-is-back-up-and-running-after-being-forced-to-shut-down-its-services-because-of-the-wirecard-scandal/

Answer (score 18):

Django is as secure as any web framework can be. It provides tools and doc to prevent common mistakes causing security problems (csrf, xss, etc.)

However, a tool in itself cannot be "secure". The whole platform security depends on the proper use of the tools you choose, and thus is more a matter of developer skills.

Answer (score 8):

As a web framework it hat some functions that will help you in making your site secure.
You can't directly say of a web-framework it is secure.

In the end its all about how your client designs his project.
Django is used in big projects and therefore it has proven to be used in a production environment. [DISQUS](http://disqus.com) is one of the best examples for that.#

If your client is willing to put some effort into securing his site he will be fine with django or any other framework but its not the framework that makes a site secure its how a developer uses the framework.

Answer (score 4):

Django is one of the most secure web frameworks. Django provides ways to protect against some common web application vulnerabilities out of the box such as -

- SQL Injection
- CRLF Injection
- Timing Attack
- Clickjacking Attack
- Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)
- Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
- HTTP Strict Transport Security (SSL)
- Session Hijacking
- Denial of Service (DoS)
- Miscellaneous

I had a similar situation, then I went through official documentation and multiple resources. I gathered and compiled all the details here-

https://gauravvjn.medium.com/secrets-of-security-in-a-django-application-0dfb41957eb0

Answer (score 1):

Security in Django - 
 By default, Django prevents most common security mistakes:
    Cross site scripting (XSS) protection
    Cross site request forgery (CSRF) protection
    SQL injection protection
    Clickjacking protection
    SSL/HTTPS
    Host header validation

Comment: Hey Sourav, thanks for the answer, do you have any references for the same?

Comment: Yes @NaveedHasan please check - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/